# how to see the strength of the bluetooth signal with Cordova?

Tags: android, bluetooth, javascript

How can I see bluetooth signal strenght in an Ionic project?I need advice to start a project where the app can show the bluetooth signal and do certain things ... The target is to develop an app for android, I have experience with Ionic,Cordova and Android Studio. How can I start?

Comment: off-topic question, should go in https://stackoverflow.com/ at least.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to use java(in android studio)but it's really hard for my level,and I  want to try ionic...